# Go: truthy condition not executing

Tags: go, neo4j

I am using neo4j in for one of my applications.

After running a query if the values are found, `result.Next()` returns a `bool`

```golang
    var matches []int 
    fmt.Println(result.Next(), "<== result NEXT ???") //  this prints true 
    if result.Next() {
        //  for some reason this block won't run!
        fmt.Println("Assigning the values to the var")
        matches = result.Record().Values()[0].([]int)
        fmt.Println("Matches found", matches)
    }
```

I would really appreciate the help, stuck on it for hours

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `result.Next()` proceeds to the next row. If you call it twice, you skip a row. `result.Next()` is not idempotent! If you have only a single result, calling `result.Next()`, the second call will never return `true`.

If you need to examine the result of `result.Next()` at multiple places, store it in a variable:

```
var matches []int 
hasNext := result.Next()
fmt.Println(hasNext, "<== result NEXT ???") 
if hasNext {
    fmt.Println("Assigning the values to the var")
    matches = result.Record().Values()[0].([]int)
    fmt.Println("Matches found", matches)
}
```

Quoting from the offical docs: [Consuming results:](https://neo4j.com/docs/go-manual/current/session-api/#go-driver-simple-result-consume)

```
for result.Next() {
    list = append(list, result.Record().Values[0].(string))
}
```

As you can see, results are iterated over by simply calling `result.Next()`.

Comment: This makes so much sense. So what I understand is `result.Next()` (used in fmt.Println) mutated and changed the pointer to the next record (which does not exist in my case ), so the second time when I used the `same` as a check, it gave returned false.

Comment: @KaranKumar Yes, that's correct.